# After moving a Wordpress site to a new server everything is working except the "More Types" plugin

Tags: wordpress

All files were copied and the MySQL database was backed-up and restored to the new server. Everything else seems to be working fine except the "More Types" plugin. Even its sister-plugin "More Fields" is working fine.

Has anyone else ever encountered this and if so how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL backed-up and restored how ?
did you run update queries on the new server ??
like so :

```
 UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

    /**
    After that you will need to fix URLs of the WordPress posts and pages, which translated from post slug, and stored in database wp_posts table as guid field. The URL values in this field are stored as abolute URLs instead of relative URLs, so it needs to be changed with the following SQL query:
    **/

    UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');

    /**
    If you have linked internally within blog posts or pages with absolute URLs, these links will point to wrong locations after you move the blog location. Use the following SQL commands to fix all internal links to own blog in all WordPress posts and pages:
    **/

    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Comment: Yes we did include this in the update. I can see a record in the wp_options table with an option_name of 'more_types' and it looks like it includes all of my types and their options with nothing specific about the old site. Does More Types store anything in a file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

HAha found the problem. The options table contains string length values for the option values, so changing the domain value without changing the string length value breaks the plugin.

This:

```
s:23:"http://old-domain.com"
```

became:

```
s:23:"http://my-new-domain.com"
```

The s:23 is invalid and will need to be changed as well. One way around this would be to change all full paths for your plugin options to relative paths...which is what I did ;)